# Convert a multi-type 2D matrix to a float Matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, casting

I set my data into a 2D matrix and now I have a matrix of multi-type matrix and I need to convert all values to float but Strings.

for example, one row of my matrix is like this: ['0', 'N', '1.1', '0.555', 'No', '23', 'yes']
I am trying to do this but I will face an error:

```
floatMatrix = [ [ np.float64(eachVal) for eachVal in row ] for row in data]
```

Error is this:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'N'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`try-except` fits your case. I would suggest a little better function than @Psidom as you want to convert all values to float.

```
def convert(x, default=0):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except:
        return default
```

Creating your converted data:

`floatMatrix = [ [ convert(eachVal) for eachVal in row ] for row in data]`

Answer (score 0):

Write a customized function to convert elements in your matrix to float, if it is not possible, i.e. strings, return the element. Then use the function to convert the type of the elements in the list:

```
def conv(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except:
        return x

[conv(x) for x in row]
# [0.0, 'N', 1.1, 0.555, 'No', 23.0, 'yes']
```